# clarification on validating a textbox

Tags: javascript, css, html, validation

I have totally 6 textboxes here and i have applied different validations for them but none of them are working. here is my code can someone help me out where i have gone wrong. 
Each textbox have different condition

1)it should accept only alphabets

2)it should accept only numbers

3)it should accept only email

4)it should accept only alphabets if u enter anything other then alphabet and press submit button background color of that particular textbox will change

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head> 
<title> Text Boxes </title>
<script>

function test(){

    if(form.alphabets.value == "") {
        alert('Please enter name');
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!form.alphabets.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
            return false;
        }
    }


    if(form.numbers.value == "") {
        alert('Please enter phone number ');
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!form.numbers.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        form.numbers.value="";
        form.numbers.focus(); 
        alert("Please Enter only numbers");
        return false;       
        }
    }

    if(form.email.value == "") {
        alert('Please enter email ');
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!form.email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/) ) {
            form.email.value="";
            alert("Please Enter Valid email address");
            form.email.focus(); 
            return false;
        }   
    }

    if(form.alphabets1.value == "") {
        alert('Please don't enter numbers ');
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!form.alphabets1.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            form.alphabets1.value="";
            form.alphabets1.focus(); 
            form.alphabets1.style.background="Red";
            alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
            return false;
        }

    }

function check()
{
var text = document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value;
if(text.length >= 4)
{

    alert('Length should not be greater than 4');
    return false;
} 
else 
{

return true;
}

}


function sum()
{
var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
   txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
   txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;

}
</script>


</head>


<body>

<form name="form" method ="post"> 
<table>     
    <tr>
        <td>Enter only Alphabets :</td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="alphabets" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter only Numbers :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="numbers" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter your Email Address : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter only alphabets</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="alphabets1"</td>
    </tr>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>




</table>

<button onclick="test();"> click me </button>

            <td><br></td>
            <td></br></td>

<div>
  Enter only 4 values : <input type="text" length="3" id="txtarea_content" onkeypress="return check();"> </textarea>
</div>


<tr>
        <td>Enter Two Numbers : <input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" />
                <input type="text" id="txt2"  onkeyup="sum();" /> 
                </td>
        <td> Result :<input type="text" id="txt3" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy code error you function test() mistake `}` and   `alert('Please don't enter numbers ')` error ' in don't .Please correct the code!
 Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

why not try to get their id instead..here is the code

```
var alpa = document.getElementById('alphabets');
if(alpa.value == "") {
    alert('Please enter name');
    return;
} else {
    if (!alpa.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
        return;
    }
}
```

hope this'll help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here. Single quote(') ends unnecessary in the middle. Use double quotes(") in that place.

Instead of this

```
if(form.alphabets1.value == "") {
    alert('Please don't enter numbers ');
    return false;
}
```

Use this

```
if(form.alphabets1.value == "") {
    alert("Please don't enter numbers ");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As tuan huynh said, you forgot to close the function test statement with }. In addition, have you think that some people would end up entering spaces in the name - because they have two names, for example? This regexp would accept those spaces (keep in mind that \w is the same than a-zA-Z ):

```
/^[\w|\s]+$/
```

People may even want to put accents on vowels or similar symbols in their names, and they won't match with a regexp that only looks for alphabets. This would make it, at least, for accents:

```
/^[\w|\s|á-úÁ-Ú|à-ùÀ-Ù]+$/
```

I hope this helps.